# autoconf set library search path

Tags: macos, autoconf, automake

So on mac I have to export the library path and include path for OpenSSl because it's in `/opt/brew`. I have tried a couple of different things with setting it in both the `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` but when I do `./configure` it fails to find the library because it never added the path to the checking gcc command.

In `Makefile.am` i have tried doing `LDFLAGS += ~myPath~` but that doesn't work.